# Print the next element of a row in new column

Tags: awk, sed

I have a very big file in this format:

```
1       10802
1       10876
1      10952
1      11813
```

I want write it in this format:

```
1    10802 10876 74
```

The first column, second column, second element of the second column be the first element of third column, and $4=$3-$2 i.e. fourth column should be subtraction of column 3 and column 2.

Comment: The second row will be 1 10876 10952 76

Comment: What have you scripted so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can make it:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{p=$2; next} {print $1, p, $2, $2-p; p=$2}' file
1 10802 10876 74
1 10876 10952 76
1 10952 11813 861
```

#### Explanation

- `NR==1{p=$2; next}` when we are in the first row, just store the second column in the variable `p` and skip row.
- `{print $1, p, $2, $2-p; p=$2}` from there, keep printing the values as this: 1st col, `p` (stored value), 2nd col, difference. Then, store the value of the 2nd column in the variable `p` for the next loop.

Comment: A big +1 for figuring out the requirements! I was stumped!